Is the flap a stop, a liquid, or something else?
The flap sounds like a fast [d], and is represented in IPA like [ɾ]. Is it a stop like [d] or a liquid like [r]? If neither, which class is it? see this table from Yule's Study of Languages for classifications.


What research have you attempt to answer this question? Which linguistics resources, glossaries or encyclopedias have you consulted? This question as you have phrased it appears very basic. If the resources you have consulted already are not adequate to answer the question, or if they have conflicting information, you will need to edit this to explain in detail. Otherwise this question is likely to be closed.

The consonantal sound denoted by [ɾ] in the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) is categorized as a flap. As a general rule in linguistics, it is important to note that phonetic categories such as stops, liquids, and trills are largely theoretical constructs. In practice, the articulation of speech sounds often spans a continuum, and many phones, especially consonantal ones, do not fit neatly into these predefined categories. This variability is inherent in the nature of human phonetic production.
Regarding the [ɾ] sound, while it is classified as a flap, it shares several characteristics with stops. Specifically, a flap involves a brief contact between the articulators, similar to a stop. However, unlike stops, flaps only involve a very slight buildup of intraoral pressure and do not exhibit a release burst, or at most, only a very slight one, as previously mentioned. This absence of notable air pressure buildup and release distinguishes flaps from traditional stops.
Additionally, flaps can exhibit characteristics akin to trills. A trill typically involves multiple rapid contacts between the articulators, as exemplified by the sound [r]. However, a trill can, in some instances, be realized with a single contact, as seen with [ɾ]. Despite this overlap, a key differentiating factor is that a flap, by definition, involves only a single articulatory contact, whereas trills can encompass multiple contacts. Thus, while the [ɾ] sound shares similarities with both stops and trills, it is uniquely defined by its single, rapid articulation without the accompanying buildup of air pressure.

A tap is effected by voluntary motion of the articulator, whereas in a trill the motion of the articulator is caused by the airstream moving over it. A tap and a single-contact trill are fundamentally different things.

My original statement remains valid. You just felt the need to add another defining factor.
